# Halloween answer-a-thon

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, events

I created an event: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule

for an answer marathon, after Martin commented in 'You Are Here' that it'd worked on the TeX site.  Hopefully people are for the idea of a 3 hour window (or however many you can provide) where we really churn through the site and try and add a few extra answers that we think can help, and especially knock off some of the unanswered ones that have been sitting there a while - although we're doing pretty well with those.

If you're going to join, or even if you can and just think it's a good idea, give this a vote and add your name in to the event.  It'll be good to do it together while having the chat room open for a good travel chat, and meet some of the regulars in the chat room (just don't ask about naked urls or quote any of Journey's 'Don't stop believing' song) ;)

EDIT: A reminder that if you visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule, it will tell you the schedule IN YOUR TIMEZONE - and infact now that it's less than a day to go, will tell you in how many hours it kicks off.

If you can't make it, feel free to try and add 10 answers to questions (preferably unanswered) as close to that time as you can manage.  And have a tab in the chat room for support ;)

Comment: Just so we are clear, this is 31 Oct 09:00 PM UTC (i.e. 21:00)?

Comment: if you go to the schedule page, it tells you it in your timezone.

Comment: Why not keep it in main chat room?

Comment: er, yeah, about that, it IS actually scheduled for the main chat room, I was just creating the other room to discuss it in before I then put it on meta. will fix up now.

Comment: taken care of :)